# Run time error '13' type miss match

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am trying to run a macro that will automatically insert the formula

```
=IFERROR(IF('307'!A2=0,"-",'307'!A2),"-")
```

When I have the VBA code setup with the code below it does not work. I just get the type mismatch error.

```
Range("B2:B33").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF('307'!A2=0," - ",'307'!A2)," - ")"
```

Essentially what I want to have happen is the formula to be inserted and then the next formula would have 'A3' the next 'A4' and so on. Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the quotes to show then you need to double them in vba:

```
"=IFERROR(IF('307'!A2=0,"" - "",'307'!A2),"" - "")"
```

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Craner pointed out:  In order to escape quotes "you need to double them".

Here is an easy trick to double all of your quotes.

[image]

> ?Replace(Range("A1").Formula,Chr(34),Chr(34)& Chr(34))
>
> =IFERROR(IF('307'!A2=0,""-"",'307'!A2),""-"")